# "Unknowm column in field list" - error from truncated column name

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I built a prepared statement which renames `TEST01` columns into columns mapped in a table named  `MAPPING`.

For a specific column named 'localization', I get this error message: MySQL said: #1054 - Unknown column 'loca' in 'field list' .  I don't understand why this one in particular since there are other columns with longer names and they did not trigger the same error.

```
BEGIN
    SELECT CONCAT(
        'CREATE TABLE `table_client_normalized` AS SELECT * FROM (SELECT ',
     GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(client_label, ' AS ', master_label)), ', ',  
        QUOTE(MAX(clientid)), ' AS client_id ',
      'FROM TEST01'
    ') A' ) INTO @sql
        FROM `MAPPING` B;

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

I compared the data structure on each table and aligned them to: varchar(100), utf8_bin.

If I rename the columns (both on `TEST01` and `MAPPING`) into `loca` or anything shorter than 4 characters, the query will work.

So, it seems to be a size issue but I don't understand the reason behind, why the problem only on that specific column and what to do to solve this issue.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you post final query created over here ? So that we can know whether query is having correct syntax or not? It seems like there is a special character in your `client_label` field. You can know final query by just inserting `select @sql` above `prepare stmt from @sql` line.

Comment: Here is the query in the case that works otherwise it does not show:
    CREATE TABLE `table_client_normalized` AS SELECT * FROM (SELECT client AS cont_id,commande AS transaction_id,no_ligne AS line_id,date_commande_client AS transaction_date,intitule AS store_name, 'tes' AS client_id FROM TEST01) A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat:

> The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the
>   group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of
>   1024.

Comment: I don't understand why this column in particular causes the error since there are other columns with longer names and they did not trigger the same error.

Comment: I assume it's because it's the last one, and it goes just over the configured limit. It might be helpful if you post all the column names in the question.

Comment: Changed the limit to 2024 and it worked! Thank you Alex R.